# FiniteElement v.s. TensorProductGrid: which is reliable for Schrödinger equation with periodic b.c.?

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, complex, finite-element-method, finite-difference-method

This is a problem comes up in the discussion under [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/188069/1871) and I think it's worth starting a new question for it.

I suspect the underlying issue is the same as in [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/124737/1871), but not sure.

Consider the following example:

```
mol[n:_Integer|{_Integer..}, o_:"Pseudospectral"] := {"MethodOfLines", 
  "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MaxPoints" -> n, 
    "MinPoints" -> n, "DifferenceOrder" -> o}}

molfem[measure_: Automatic] := {"MethodOfLines", 
   "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
     "MeshOptions" -> MaxCellMeasure -> measure}};

Clear@solve;
tend = 5;
solve[opt_] := 
 NDSolveValue[{I D[u[t, x], t] == -D[u[t, x], {x, 2}] + I Sin[x] u[t, x], 
   u[0, x] == Exp[-x^2] Exp[I x], u[t, -Pi] == u[t, Pi]}, u, {t, 0, tend}, {x, -Pi, Pi}, 
  Method -> opt]

soltraditional = solve@mol[200, 4]
solfem = solve@molfem[]

Plot[{ReIm@solfem[tend, x], ReIm@soltraditional[tend, x]}, {x, -π, π}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Plot[{Abs@solfem[tend, x], Abs@soltraditional[tend, x]}, {x, -π, π}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The difference is obvious.

Which solution is the reliable one?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't run this because I have V10.0.1, and I can't tell just by looking at the real and imaginary parts, but are the absolute-squares of the wave functions different as well?

Comment: @march Yes. See my update.

Comment: I'd assumed that you would have checked, but it helps to make sure!

Comment: @xzczd This is amazing and should be explored.

Answer (score 7):

Plugging the solutions into the PDE yields for `soltraditional`

```
(I D[u[t, x], t] + D[u[t, x], {x, 2}] - I Sin[x] u[t, x]) /. u -> soltraditional;
Plot3D[Evaluate@ReIm@%, {x, -Pi, Pi}, {t, 0, tend}, PlotRange -> All, 
    ImageSize -> Large, AxesLabel -> {x, t, u}, LabelStyle -> {Bold, Black, 15}]
```

[image]

which is not so good, the spiky behavior near `t == tend` suggesting the onset of instability.  In contrast, the result for `solfem` is simply terrible, as though it were the solution of a different  PDE!

[image]

The discrepancies are not associated particularly with the boundary conditions, suggesting that the problem here is not the same as in the [second post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/124765/1063) mentioned in the question.

```
Plot[{ReIm@(solfem[t, Pi] - solfem[t, -Pi]), 
      ReIm@(soltraditional[t, Pi] - soltraditional[t, Pi])}, {t, 0, tend},
      PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> Large, AxesLabel -> {t, u}, 
      LabelStyle -> {Bold, Black, 15}]
```

[image]

To answer the specific question posed by the OP, `soltraditional` is much more credible than `solfem`.

**Addendum: Solutions with potential eliminated**

Repeating these computations with the term `I Sin[x] u[t, x]` eliminated from the PDE yields somewhat similar results.  The `soltraditional` solution is noisy but now shows no sign of instability.  The `solfem` solution again does not satisfy the PDE.

At least superficially, this looks like a bug.