# Heat Flow in a Pipe

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, physics

I try to model the  transient heat flow  in a pipe, assuming that the temperature in radial direction doesn't change:

temperature `u[t, \[CurlyPhi], z] , 0<z<10,0<\[CurlyPhi]<2Pi`

The flux boundary conditions are described by `NeumannValue`. In direction of  circumference two continuity conditions are considered:

Evaluating my model

```
NDSolveValue[{ 2.4 10^6   Derivative[1, 0, 0][u][t, \[CurlyPhi], z] == 172 (Derivative[0, 0, 2][u][t, \[CurlyPhi], z] +30.5 Derivative[0, 2, 0][u][t, \[CurlyPhi], z])
+ 1/138 1.85 10^7 NeumannValue[1, (-10 \[Degree] <= \[CurlyPhi]<= 10 \[Degree]) &&z == 10    ] 
+ NeumannValue[0, (- 10 \[Degree]  <= \[CurlyPhi] <= 10 \[Degree]) &&z ==  0  ] 
, u[0, \[CurlyPhi], z] == 0
, u[t, 0, z] == u[t, 2 Pi, z]
, Derivative[0, 1, 0][u][t, 0, z] ==Derivative[0, 1, 0][u][t, 2 Pi, z]},
u,{t, 0, 1}, {\[CurlyPhi], 0, 2 Pi}, {z, 0, 10} 
, Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "TemporalVariable" -> t,"SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid" }}]

(*NDSolveValue::bcart: Warning: an insufficient number of 
boundary conditions have been specified for the direction of 
independent variable z. Artificial boundary effects may be present in the solution.*)
```

gives an error message "insufficient boundary conditions  in z-direction", inspite of two `NeumannValue's`,  which I don't understand

What's wrong with my code? Thanks!

**addendum #1(21.11.2019)** (thanks for the several contributions! )

Substituting `NeumannValue` by explicit `Derivative`-boundaries the modified simulation

```
NDSolveValue[{ 2.4 10^6 (Derivative[1, 0, 0][u][t, \[CurlyPhi], z] ) ==172 (Derivative[0, 0, 2][u][t, \[CurlyPhi], z] + 30.5 Derivative[0, 2, 0][u][t, \[CurlyPhi], z])
, u[0, \[CurlyPhi], z] == 0
, u[t, 0, z] == u[t, 2 Pi, z]
, Derivative[0, 1, 0][u][t, 0, z] ==Derivative[0, 1, 0][u][t, 2 Pi, z]
, Derivative[0, 0, 1][u][t, \[CurlyPhi], 10] == If[-10 \[Degree] <= \[CurlyPhi]<= 10 \[Degree],1/138 1.85 10^7 , 0]
, Derivative[0, 0, 1][u][t, \[CurlyPhi], 0] == 0},
u,{t, 0, 1}, {\[CurlyPhi], 0, 2 Pi}, {z, 0, 10}, Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "TemporalVariable" -> t,"SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid" }}
```

runs without error but only evaluates the solution `u==0`, that means the flux boundary at `z==0` doesn't contribute to the solution???

**addendum #2(21.11.2019)**

Learning&Knowing that flux boundaries might be more  easier formulated in `FEM` I tried to find a executable FEM-model:

```
NDSolveValue[{2.4 10^6 Derivative[1, 0, 0][u][t, \[CurlyPhi], z] ==172 (Derivative[0, 0, 2][u][t, \[CurlyPhi], z] + 30.5 Derivative[0, 2, 0][u][t, \[CurlyPhi], z]) + 
1/138 1.85 10^7 NeumannValue[1, (-10 \[Degree] <= \[CurlyPhi] <= 10 \[Degree]) && z ==  10] +
NeumannValue[0, (-10 \[Degree] <= \[CurlyPhi] <= 10 \[Degree]) && z ==  0], u[0, \[CurlyPhi], z] == 0
, PeriodicBoundaryCondition[u[t, \[CurlyPhi], z], \[CurlyPhi] ==  \[Pi],Function[\[Phi], \[Phi] - 2 \[Pi]]]}, 
u, {t, 0, 1}, {\[CurlyPhi], -Pi, Pi}, {z, 0, 10}, 
Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "TemporalVariable" -> t, "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement"}}]
```

But Mathematica gives error message `NDSolveValue::bcnop: No places were found on the boundary where -10 \[Degree]<=\[CurlyPhi]<=10 \[Degree]&&z==0 was True, so NeumannValue[0,-10 \[Degree]<=\[CurlyPhi]<=10 \[Degree]&&z==0] will effectively be ignored.`

What's wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: I think the periodic boundary conditions should be formulated with, well, `PeriodicBoundaryCondition`. E.g. `PeriodicBoundaryCondition[u[t, \[Phi], z], \[Phi] == 2 \[Pi],  Function[\[Phi], \[Phi] - 2 \[Pi]]]` and `PeriodicBoundaryCondition[
 Derivative[0, 1, 0][u][t, \[Phi], z], \[Phi] == 2 \[Pi], 
 Function[\[Phi], \[Phi] - 2 \[Pi]]]`. However, _Mathematica_ complains about the latter. =|

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Thanks, it's dodgy...

Comment: @Henrik Schumacher, what leads you to belive that? Maybe I need to improve the documentation?

Comment: One obvious mistake is, you're using `TensorProductGrid` together with `NeumannValue`, but `NeumannValue` is only for `FiniteElement`, at least now.

Comment: @xzczd Thanks. In the documentation of `NeumannValue` I didn't find that restriction. It would  imply that no flux -conditions could be imposed with `TensorPorductGrid`and difference-methods?

Comment: No, you can use the old good `Derivative` to express the flux condition when `TensorProductGrid` is chosen.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann, I have added that the NeumannValue is for FEM in the 12.1 documentation.

Comment: @xzczd Using "good old" `Derivative` how to restrict the parameter range `(- 10 \[Degree]  <= \[CurlyPhi] <= 10 \[Degree]) &&z ==  0` (for example)?

Comment: @user21 Thanks!

Comment: Just use a `If` or `Piecewise`. (BTW, you might need to use ``Simplify`PWToUnitStep`` to circumvent certain bug(s), for example: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/137838/1871 )

Comment: @xzczd I tried to implement your suggestions(see my modified question) but the flux boundary seems to be ignored...

Comment: As to the #2, the underlying issue is similar to #1: the default mesh is too coarse to capture the Neumann value, add `"SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.05}}` fix the issue.

Comment: @xzczd Thanks! How simple!

Answer (score 4):

There are certain triggers that force the use of the finite element method. These are listed [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/140805/18437) and I am working on adding this to the FEM documentation in product. So the use of `NeumannValue` is going to force the the FEM - but that contradicts with the TensorProductGrid method you requested. So either use the finite element method (then you need to get rid of the periodic derivatives - see [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/204670/18437) ) or get rid of the `NeumannValue` to use the "TensorProductGrid" (TPG) method, which I think you want to do here. To convert the `NeuammValue` to a `Derivative` it is mandatory to understand their relation which is discussed [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementBestPractice.html#1529668360). One thing that could be done though is to make `NDSolve` give a message in that case.

You could also solve this on an Annulus (if I understand correctly what you want to do) but in either case you'd need something that drives the temperature. As a template you could use:

```
fun = NDSolveValue[{Derivative[1, 0, 0][u][t, x, y] == 
     10 (Laplacian[u[t, x, y], {x, y}]) + 
      NeumannValue[
       1, (x^+y^2 >= 2) && (x > 1 && (-1 >= y && y <= 1))], 
    u[0, x, y] == 0
    }, u, {t, 0, 1}, Element[{x, y}, Annulus[{0, 0}, {1, 2}]], 
   Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "TemporalVariable" -> t}];
ContourPlot[fun[1, x, y], {x, y} \[Element] fun["ElementMesh"]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your hints, what is "TPG method"? My understanding of `NeumannValue` is the normal derivative of the unknown function on the boundary surface. In the documentation  `NeumannValue` special  type of pde is shown, somewhat confusing for me...

Comment: @UlrichNeumann, TPG = TensorProductGrid method. Concerning the `NeumannValue`, that's not quite correct, though in some cases it can be used for that. The `NeumannValues` is tied to the `c` values in `Div[c Grad[u[x,y],{x,y}],{x,y}]`

Comment: Thank you for your comment and the template! The purpose of my question is as follows: I wrote a huge simulation model (3D hollow cylinder, cartesian coordinates , transient,>10000elements) which works quite well, but gives error message `peclet-number`. Increasing element number doesn't succeed. That's why I try to reduce this modell.

Comment: I tried to substitute the `NeumannValue` in your example by `DirichletCondition[Grad[u[t, x, y], {x, y}].{x, y} ==1, (x^2 + y^2 >= 2) && (x > 1 && (-1 >= y && y <= 1 ))]` but `TensorProductGrid`doesn't work as expected. Any idea how to make it work? Thanks!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann, Neither, `DirichletCondition` nor `NeumannValue` nor `PeriodicBoundaryCondition` can be used with the TensorProductGrid method and more in the finite element method you can not use `DirichletCondition[Grad...` either. To make this work with the TPG method you need to eliminate `DirichletCondtion`, `NeumannValue` and `PeriodicBoundaryCondition` from your code. Maybe you could have a second post with your actual 3D example?

Comment: Thanks, that means there is no possibility to formulate the flux boundary conditions in cartesian coordinates? Again it shows the advantages of `FEM`. I intend to post my 3D-example, but need some time...

Comment: @UlrichNeumann, I tink you can but you need to be careful how to formulate this. You'd need to use `Derivative` with the TPG method to model the `NeuannValue`. Probably the `Derivative` needs a factor in front of it to model the `NeumannValue`

Answer (score 4):

Your problem and @user21's answer suggests that you have half symmetry at $\pi$.  You could use `FEMAddOns` to build a FEM mesh with a heated boundary $0-5^\circ $  and solve on the domain $0-180^\circ $ like so:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
ResourceFunction["FEMAddOnsInstall"][]
Needs["FEMAddOns`"]
ht = 10;
len = 5 \[Degree];
top = ht;
bot = 0;
left = 0;
right = len;
left2 = right;
right2 = 180 \[Degree];
bounds = <|wall -> 1, hot -> 2|>;
bmeshheated = 
  ToBoundaryMesh[
   "Coordinates" -> {{left, bot}(*1*), {right, bot}(*2*), {right, 
      top}(*3*), {left, top}(*4*)}, 
   "BoundaryElements" -> {LineElement[{{1, 2}(*bottom edge*)(*1*), {4,
         1}(*left edge*)(*2*), {2, 3}(*3*), {3, 4}(*4*)}, {1, 1, 1, 
       bounds[hot]}]}];
bmeshheated[
  "Wireframe"["MeshElementMarkerStyle" -> Blue, 
   "MeshElementStyle" -> {Green, Red, Black}, ImageSize -> Large]];

bmeshinsulated = 
  ToBoundaryMesh[
   "Coordinates" -> {{left2, bot}(*1*), {right2, bot}(*2*), {right2, 
      top}(*3*), {left2, top}(*4*)}, 
   "BoundaryElements" -> {LineElement[{{1, 2}(*bottom edge*)(*1*), {4,
         1}(*left edge*)(*2*), {2, 3}(*3*), {3, 4}(*4*)}, {1, 1, 1, 
       1}]}];
bmeshinsulated[
  "Wireframe"["MeshElementMarkerStyle" -> Blue, 
   "MeshElementStyle" -> {Green, Red, Black}, ImageSize -> Large]];
bmesh = BoundaryElementMeshJoin[bmeshheated, bmeshinsulated];
bmesh["Wireframe"["MeshElementMarkerStyle" -> Blue, 
   "MeshElementStyle" -> {Green, Red, Black}, ImageSize -> Large]];
bmesh["Wireframe"];
mesh = ToElementMesh[bmesh]
mesh["Wireframe"]
```

Once you have an well defined FEM mesh, it is relative straightforward to pose the FEM problem using coefficient form.

```
rhocp = 2.4 10^6;
k = 172.;
r = Sqrt[1/30.5];
q = 1/138 1.85 10^7/2.;
nv = NeumannValue[q, ElementMarker == bounds[hot]];
op = rhocp \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(t\)]\(u[t, x, y]\)\) - 
   Inactive[
     Div][(-{{k/r^2, 0}, {0, k}}.Inactive[Grad][
        u[t, x, y], {x, y}]), {x, y}];
uif = NDSolveValue[{op == nv , u[0, x, y] == 0}, 
   u, {t, 0, 1}, {x, y} \[Element] mesh];
imgs = Plot3D[
     If[x < 0, uif[#, -x, z], uif[#, x, z]], {x, -Pi, Pi}, {z, 9.5, 
      10}, PlotRange -> {-0.1, 1.4}, ColorFunction -> "DarkBands"] & /@
    Subdivide[0, 1, 60];
ListAnimate@imgs
```

[image: Film Heating]

The mesh will need some refinement, but if you have the interpolation function, then you should be able to transform it to cylindrical coordinates.

## Update To Include Scaling and Elevated Surface

The spatial and temporal domain was very large relative to where all the action was occurring.  In these cases, non-dimensionalizing the PDE will help size the domains relative to characteristic time and length scales.  In this case, I used the concept of a penetration depth in infinite plate heating.  The penetration depth is given by:

$${y_c} = 4\sqrt {\alpha t}$$

After non-dimensionalizing the equations, we can create a domain where the flux will penetrate to the symmetry condition and to the insulate wall condition at $z=0$.  Here is the code to create a mesh on the new domain with refinement near the heater:

```
r = 1;
ht = 4 r;
len = 5 \[Degree];
top = ht;
bot = 0;
left = 0;
right = len;
left2 = right;
right2 = 180 \[Degree];
bounds = <|wall -> 1, hot -> 2|>;
bmeshheated = 
  ToBoundaryMesh[
   "Coordinates" -> {{left, bot}(*1*), {right, bot}(*2*), {right, 
      top}(*3*), {left, top}(*4*)}, 
   "BoundaryElements" -> {LineElement[{{1, 2}(*bottom edge*)(*1*), {4,
         1}(*left edge*)(*2*), {2, 3}(*3*), {3, 4}(*4*)}, {1, 1, 1, 
       bounds[hot]}]}];
bmeshheated[
  "Wireframe"["MeshElementMarkerStyle" -> Blue, 
   "MeshElementStyle" -> {Green, Red, Black}, ImageSize -> Large]];

bmeshinsulated = 
  ToBoundaryMesh[
   "Coordinates" -> {{left2, bot}(*1*), {right2, bot}(*2*), {right2, 
      top}(*3*), {left2, top}(*4*)}, 
   "BoundaryElements" -> {LineElement[{{1, 2}(*bottom edge*)(*1*), {4,
         1}(*left edge*)(*2*), {2, 3}(*3*), {3, 4}(*4*)}, {1, 1, 1, 
       1}]}];
bmeshinsulated[
  "Wireframe"["MeshElementMarkerStyle" -> Blue, 
   "MeshElementStyle" -> {Green, Red, Black}, ImageSize -> Large]];
bmesh = BoundaryElementMeshJoin[bmeshheated, bmeshinsulated];
bmesh["Wireframe"["MeshElementMarkerStyle" -> Blue, 
  "MeshElementStyle" -> {Green, Red, Black}, ImageSize -> Large]]
mesh = ToElementMesh[bmesh, 
   MeshRefinementFunction -> 
    Function[{vertices, area}, 
     area > 0.0002 (1 + 10 Norm[Mean[vertices] - {0, ht}])]];
mesh["Wireframe"]
```

### Boundary Mesh with Heated Edge Marked

[image: Boundary Mesh]

### Element Mesh Showing Refinement

[image: Refined Mesh]

We will solve the non-dimensional PDE and visualize the results with an elevated surface using `ParametricPlot3D`.

```
ct = CoordinateTransformData["Cylindrical" -> "Cartesian", "Mapping"];
rhocp = 16/Pi^2;
alpha = 1;
q = 1;
nv = NeumannValue[q, ElementMarker == bounds[hot]];
op = rhocp \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(t\)]\(u[t, x, y]\)\) - 
   Inactive[
     Div][(-{{alpha, 0}, {0, alpha}}.Inactive[Grad][
        u[t, x, y], {x, y}]), {x, y}];
uif = NDSolveValue[{op == nv , u[0, x, y] == 0}, 
   u, {t, 0, 10}, {x, y} \[Element] mesh];
ppfn =  ParametricPlot3D[{ct[{r + 10 uif[#, x, z], x, z}], 
     ct[{r + 10 uif[#, x, z], -x, z}]}, {x, z} \[Element] mesh, 
    ColorFunction -> 
     Function[{x, y, z, u, v}, 
      ColorData["SunsetColors"][10 uif[#, u, v]]], 
    ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
    MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y, z}, Norm@{x, y}]}, Mesh -> 25, 
    PlotRange -> {{-2, 4}, {-2, 2}, {0, ht}}, Boxed -> False, 
    Axes -> False, 
    ViewPoint -> {1.6822406480044492`, -1.3581436516840697`, \
-2.6029814105352025`}, 
    ViewVertical -> {0.9575175915664486`, 
      0.060531137127969`, -0.2819504269881192`}, 
    Background -> GrayLevel[.1]] &;
imgs = ppfn[#] & /@ Subdivide[0, 10, 80];
ListAnimate@imgs
```

[image: Elevated Surface]

The results seem reasonable.  The temperature is highest at the flux boundary and the pipe begins to "swell" at the zero flux conditions.

## Time Varying Heater

Something a little more interesting/mesmerizing would be to add a time varying heat flux and watch the waves propagate down the pipe, which is easily done by replacing two lines and re-running the simulation.

```
q[t_] = 1 + Sin[Pi*t] + Cos[Pi*t] + Sin[2*Pi*t] + Cos[2*Pi*t];
nv = NeumannValue[q[t], ElementMarker == bounds[hot]];
```

[image: Time Varying Neumann Value]

Comment: Thanks for your help. Symmetry is only fullfilled in my simplified example.  Additionally I need the flux boundaries.

Comment: The default boundary condition is zero flux, so a flux BC has been specified on all boundaries.

Comment: No, the flux boundary isn't zero at `z==10`!

Comment: Thanks for the impressing simulation!

Comment: You are welcome.  I updated the post to show the heated edge boundary marker (2) for clarity.  It was set to be non-zero by `nv = NeumannValue[q, ElementMarker == bounds[hot]]`.  All other boundaries are set to zero and internal boundaries are ignored.

Answer (score 1):

I'll fix the code using `TensorProductGrid` in **#1**. There're at least 5 issues:

1. Considering your b.c., the domain for $φ$ should probably be `{φ, -Pi, Pi}`.
2. The default grid is too coase (`15` points in each dimension) to capture the narrow flux at $z=0$.
3. The i.c. and b.c. are inconsistent, which leads to the problem mentioned [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127411/1871).
4. Setting a non-zero `ScaleFactor` as suggested above triggers a bug mentioned [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/137838/1871).
5. The method for ODE solving needs to be adjusted a bit, or `NDSolve` will automatically choose a rather slow method when the grid is dense enough. (It's unclear what the method is. )

After resolving all these, we obtain:

```
test = NDSolveValue[
    With[{u = u[t, φ, z]},
     {2.4 10^6 D[u, t] == 172 (D[u, z, z] + 30.5 D[u, φ, φ]),
      u == 0 /. t -> 0,
      (u /. φ -> -Pi) == (u /. φ -> Pi), 
      D[u, z] == 
        Simplify`PWToUnitStep@
         PiecewiseExpand@
          If[-10 ° <= φ <= 10 °, 1/138 1.85 10^7, 0] /. z -> 10,
      D[u, z] == 0 /. z -> 0}], u, {t, 0, 1}, {φ, -Pi, Pi}, {z, 0, 10}, 
    Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
      "DifferentiateBoundaryConditions" -> {True, "ScaleFactor" -> 10}, 
      "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MaxPoints" -> 810, 
        "MinPoints" -> 810, "DifferenceOrder" -> 4}, Method -> Adams}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* ibcinc warning *)
(* {86.9492, Null} *)

Plot[test[1, phi, 10], {phi, -Pi, Pi}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, I have to elaborate some time.  Testing your code I increased the simulation time, but the plot doesn't change, though there is no heat conduction in the pipe???

Comment: @UlrichNeumann I guess you forgot to change the time inside `Plot`?

Comment: Unfortunately not,  I tried t=3 (simulation and plot).

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Please show me your code.

Comment: Here is my code `Show[{Plot[test[3, phi, 10], {phi, -Pi, Pi}, PlotRange ->All,GridLines -> {{-10 \[Degree], 10 \[Degree]}, None}],Plot[test[1, phi, 10], {phi, -Pi, Pi}, PlotRange -> All,GridLines -> {{-10 \[Degree], 10 \[Degree]}, None}]}]`. It shows a small conduction effect!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann What do you mean by "small conduction effect"? In _v12_  the peak height is about `1300` at $t=1$ and about `2100` at $t=3$, if this isn't what you obtain, please show me the complete code sample.

Comment: Ok that's alsomy result. First I was expecting a faster temperature change in phi-direction. Thank you for your help.